# Find which cells in raster brick contain data in any layer

Tags: r, r-raster

I have some large raster bricks of gridded global data. I want to perform  some computationally demanding calculations on a cell by cell basis. To reduce computation load I want to run the model only on raster cells that contain data in at least one of the layers of the brick.  But how do I efficiently find cells that contain some data?  I know I can do it with a loop. like this:

**1st some reproducible data:**

```
library(raster)
r.list = vector("list", 20)
set.seed(123)
for (i in 1:20) {
  r.list[[i]] = raster(vals = sample(c(rep(NA,10),1), 100, TRUE), nrows = 10, ncols = 10, ext = extent(c(0,25,0,25)))
}
r.brick = brick(r.list)
```

**Now we loop through each layer of the brick to find which cells have some data:**

```
has.data.list = vector("list", 20)
for (i in 1:20) {
  has.data.list[[i]] = which(!is.na(values(raster(r.brick, layer=i))))
}
has.data = sort(unique(unlist(has.data.list)))
```

But this is rather inelegant. Is there a canonical / efficient way to get a vector of cells that contain some data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible trick could be to exploit the fact that `max()` will only return `NA` when all its input values are `NA` if you specify na.rm = TRUE.

Therefore, you could compute the max of the raster brick, and check where it is different than NA. Something like:

```
has.data = which(!is.na(getValues(max(r.brick, na.rm=TRUE))))
```

> has.data
>
> 1   2   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
>   21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  33  34 35  37  38  39  40 
>   41  42  44  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  59  60  61
>   62  64  66  67  68  69  70  71 74  75  76  77  78  79  80  82  83  85 
>   86  87  89  90  91  92  93  95  96  97  98  99 100

Comment: Thanks. +1 for neat vectorised solution. Unfortunately, as you say, rejecting cells that only contain zero could be an issue. So, better is to use `max`,  rather than `sum`.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer with the improved version in my previous comment. That way I can accept it as the correct solution.